# Expo app on iOS does not recieve the correct url (firebase dynamic links)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working on an Expo app that should be able to open to a specific screen when clicking on a link. I'm using Firebase dynamic links for this.

I can first state that everything works for android.

I have created a URL prefix on Firebase, lets call it https://test.page.link.

I have created a dynamic link for this prefix, lets call it https://test.page.link/gY5Z. When clicking on this link it should open the app and turn to https://myapp.com/about so my app can navigate to the about screen.

I use this code in App.js to get the url and show it in an alert:

```
const url = useURL();

useEffect(() => {
  Alert.alert("URL", url);
}, [url]);
```

On android, when clicking the link, the alert tells me the url I get is https://myapp.com/about, and it navigates to the about screen.

On iOS, clicking on the link opens the app, but the alert tells me the url is https://test.page.link/gY5Z, which is wrong. The url should turn into https://myapp.com/about just like it does on android.

This is how my https://test.page.link/.well-known/apple-app-site-association looks like. I haven't made this myself, it was generated by Firebase.
The Team ID I got from the Apple developer team, and the bundleIdentifier is the same as in app.json.

```
{
  "applinks":
  {
    "apps":[],
    "details":
    [
      {
        "appID":"<TeamID>.<bundleIdentifier>",
        "paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my app.json I have this in expo.ios

```
"ios": {
  "icon": "./assets/launch-icon-ios.png",
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "<bundleIdentifier>",
  "infoPlist": {
    "NSRemindersUsageDescription": "This app uses the calendar"
  },
  "config": {
    "googleMapsApiKey": "<Google maps api key>"
  },
  "associatedDomains": ["applinks:test.page.link"]
},
```

The problem is the part where I click the link https://test.page.link/gY5Z and enter the app, but the url I get is https://test.page.link/gY5Z instead of https://myapp.com/about.

My best guess is the problem lies in the file located at https://test.page.link/.well-known/apple-app-site-association as seen above.
Or the problem lies in the ios part of app.json, probably in this part in that case
`"associatedDomains": ["applinks:test.page.link"]`

But I can't figure it out, and was hoping someone here might have an idea.

PS. might be good to add that I build the app with `eas build`

PS. I forgot to add that in my app.json, I have scheme set to https:

`expo: {"scheme": "https"}`